# How to find the lattice points between two given coordinates

Tags: math, linear-algebra

Let's say that I am given two coordinates (A and B) on a 2D plane. Is there a mathematical formula to calculate the coordinates of all the lattice points between A and B? I've been looking forever but can't find anything.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: please share what have you tried

Comment: what is the type of lattice? what is meant by between two _points_? do you mean _lines_

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

The line between two arbitrary points on a plane will not pass through any integer lattice points in general. However, you can generate a list of "nearby" lattice points by looping between the integer x values in between x1 and x2 to find corresponding nearby integer y values and then looping over integer y values between y1 and y2 to find corresponding nearby integer x values.